# Add Switch widget to ActionBar and respond to change event

Tags: android, android-actionbar, togglebutton

Can I know how to add Switch widget in ActionBar and handle the click event or toggle change event.

For now I can inflate the Switch in ActionBar but unable to respond to change event. I have added below to main.xml.

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="com.example.MainActivity" >

    <item
        android:id="@+id/toggleservice"
        android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
        android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        android:title="@string/toggle_service"/>

</menu>
```

I want to start a service when user clicks on switch and change it's state. Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to call [`MenuItem.getActionView`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getActionView%28%29), here's an example:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate your Menu
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.your_menu, menu);

    // Get the action view used in your toggleservice item
    final MenuItem toggleservice = menu.findItem(R.id.toggleservice);
    final Switch actionView = (Switch) toggleservice.getActionView();
    actionView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            // Start or stop your Service
        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, searched everywhere but was unable to find any solution. You just saved my day. Thanks a ton :)

Comment: Same here, where did you find this? any book or recomended lecture?

Comment: @demil133 [Just the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/MenuItem.html#getActionView%28%29)

Comment: Note that: 
xml file should only contain "switsh"

Answer (score 0):

For those of you using Xamarin. This is the translated version of adneal's answer:

```
private Switch _actionViewSwitch;

public override bool OnCreateOptionsMenu(IMenu menu)
{
    MenuInflater.Inflate(Resource.Menu.main_activity_actions, menu);

    var menuItem = menu.FindItem(Resource.Id.toggleservice);
    _actionViewSwitch = (Switch) menuItem.ActionView;
    _actionViewSwitch.CheckedChange += ActionViewOnCheckedChange;

    return base.OnCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
}

private void ActionViewOnCheckedChange(object sender, CompoundButton.CheckedChangeEventArgs checkedChangeEventArgs)
{
    // ToDo: stuff that happens when switch gets checked.
}
```