# null pointer exception in action bar menu item

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I implement switch in action bar it gives me error Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference

menu xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/toggleservice"
    android:actionViewClass="android.widget.Switch"
    android:showAsAction="ifRoom"
    android:title=""/>
```

Main activity

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    final MenuItem toggleservice = menu.findItem(R.id.toggleservice);
    final Switch actionView = (Switch) toggleservice.getActionView();
    actionView.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {
            if (isChecked){
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Checked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "UnChecked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }
    });
    return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);

}
```

logcat error

```
03-28 12:09:43.556 10445-10445/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                               Process: com.example.prem.weatherapp, PID: 10445
                                               java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(android.widget.CompoundButton$OnCheckedChangeListener)' on a null object reference
                                                   at com.example.prem.weatherapp.activity.MainActivity.onCreateOptionsMenu(MainActivity.java:92)
                                                   at android.app.Activity.onCreatePanelMenu(Activity.java:2850)
                                                   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onCreatePanelMenu(FragmentActivity.java:362)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatDelegateImplBase$AppCompatWindowCallbackBase.onCreatePanelMenu(AppCompatDelegateImplBase.java:335)
                                                   at android.support.v7.view.WindowCallbackWrapper.onCreatePanelMenu(WindowCallbackWrapper.java:98)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar.populateOptionsMenu(ToolbarActionBar.java:454)
                                                   at android.support.v7.app.ToolbarActionBar$1.run(ToolbarActionBar.java:61)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:746)
                                                   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5443)
                                                   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:728)
                                                   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.Switch.setOnCheckedChangeList

Comment: Read the error. I'm sure you can figure it out. I know it can be scary but don't get intimidated.

Comment: Check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22918812/add-switch-widget-to-actionbar-and-respond-to-change-event